# JQuery Mobile dialog fields clearing issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery mobile and need some assistance in solving an issue. I have four  links in a jsp page implemented through jquery mobile framework. Each link on click opens different jquery modal dialogs. Each link opens a new jsp in modal dialog. I have some common fields on all the dialogs and i used same ids for those fields in all the dialogs. 
The issue is when i open a dialog and enter values and submits the form and comeback to parent page and again open a new dialog, the values of the common fields are showing up in the new dialog. I want to show a form with empty fields whenever i open the modal dialog. Pls help me on how to acheive this.

Comment: You might want to post a snippet of your code so it's easier for us to help you out.

Comment: my issue is similar: click a few radio buttons, open a dialog, close dialog and the radio buttons are reset.  Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the same exact JSP for each modal view form.

2 options I see here:

1. Clear the inputs on submit of the modal form

   ```
   $('#submit').click(function(){
       //Empty fields here
       $('#name').val('');
   });
   ```
2. Clear inputs on pageinit

   ```
   $('#modalForm').on('pageinit', function(){
       $('#name').val('');
   });
   ```